# could not write file C:\Users\Tato\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP3658.tmp, No space left on device

Tags: android, space

I am new to Android Studio.  I was developing a simple app with a few text input fields.  I had 10GB of unused space on my hard drive. Every time I run the the app, it takes about 1.5GB of space (used to run the emulator; Nexus 5 api23). When I close the emulator by pressing the X button in the window, the hard disk storage is not returned back to the hard drive. When I run the emulator again, it again takes 1.5GB. I continued until i got this error:

> could not write file C:\Users\Tato\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\TMP3658.tmp,
>       No space left on device

When I go to that path, the folder is empty. I don't know where to go to clean the previous emulator runs that took all the space. There must be something to clear and reclaim the storage.  I am tired of looking and cannot find anything. I usually uninstall the android studio and install it again to regain the disk storage used by avd. I don't want to do that anymore. Can someone point me in right direction to reclaim the storage and make it so that every time I run the avd it doesn't take 1.5GB? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember path, but there is folder where cache of every emulator is saved. I'm using AS 2.0 now, seems that they fixed this problem. Try to find this folder with Tree size free or any other program like this. http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/